# Как подключить SwiperJS по npm на NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper

Как подключить SwiperJS по npm на NuxtJS?

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/vue/

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаешь модуль: *npm install swiper vue-awesome-swiper --save*

Создаешь плагин: plugins/swiper.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { Swiper as SwiperClass, Pagination, Navigation, Mousewheel, Autoplay } from 'swiper/swiper.esm'
import getAwesomeSwiper from 'vue-awesome-swiper/dist/exporter'
SwiperClass.use([Pagination, Mousewheel, Navigation, Autoplay])

Vue.use(getAwesomeSwiper(SwiperClass))
```

После этого добавляешь конфигурацию в nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/swiper', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

Подробнее тут: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper